# PHP Script owner/group/permissions on non ".txt" filetypes

Tags: php, apache, chmod, chown, chgrp

I need to change the permissions and owner / group on a series of files within a folder on an Apache server w/PHP 4.  My script will change the info if it is of type .txt (text file).  But will not chmod, chown, chgrp for files with an extension of .incl (include) files which are copied into HTML/PHP files via the include or require function.

Can someone help me understand this.  The folder is a 0777, the incl files are 0644 with owner glnorg / group users (created by my  filezilla login).

I need to change to the following:  owner nobody / group nogroup  so the user can log in to their website and edit under their login (albeit generic).

Otherwise the editor, when saving, gives a permission warning message (annoying).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chmod 777 *.txt`
What it will do is assign full read and write permission to all txt files in the folder for all users and group.
However you can change the permission from 777 as per your need.

Comment: The *.txt files can be chmod, chown, chgrp without any problems with my PHP script.

The problem are the *.incl files.  None of the chmod, chown, chgrp commands within my PHP script will work.

Was thinking about renaming the *.incl file to a *.txt file, then seeing if I could chmod, chown, chgrp, the rename the file back to its *.incl.

Just seems like a whole lot of extra I/O.

Is there a PHP command that will "add" *.incl to the list of actionable filetypes....